task :stripe stripe-react-native:compiledebugkotlin failed
When i try to build my project react native with stripe he give error task :stripe stripe-react-native:compiledebugkotlin failed the version of my kotlin is 1.8.21 and gradle 8.1.1 i founded many solution in the internet but nothing changed please help me .
Found a solution for this error

is it possible to give more detail such as the full stack trace and error messages?

task :stripe stripe-react-native:compiledebugkotlin failed this is the error message when i build the app, the app without stripe work without any problem
